Is 'airflow db migrate' idempotent and can I run it as part of an entrypoint script?
I have an airflow instance running inside a docker container. I might want to update Airflow in the future while ensuring that the database matches the current version of airflow.
Can I run airflow db migrate as part of an initialization script (i.e. entrypoint.sh) that runs every time the docker container is started?

Surely you can.
I use chart bitnami/airflow, and airflow db migrate always be run during initializing.
